# Apache File Permissions: 2 files, one serves one doesn't

Tags: apache, permissions

I've got a fresh install of Apache on RHEL 6, and when I try to browse some of the files in the doc root, I get a **403 Permission Denied** error. Because I'm trying to install Wordpress, I have all of the Wordpress files in that directory, and those are the ones I cannot browse. But, while working on the problem, I created two new files and can get to them both! So, though all of the files in that folder have identical file permissions, some are being served and some are being blocked.

Here's an example:

```
    -rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache  7360 May  6 18:07 readme.html
    -rw-r--r--.  1 apache apache    73 Jun 25 21:38 test.html
```

The readme.html is not being served, it produces a 403 error, the test.html is being served. Same owner, group, and perm's, but one is not being served! The same thing is happening with the PHP files. The one I created, *info.php* works, but none of the Wordpress PHP files work, they all produce the 403 error.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, selinux was the culprit! Because I unpacked the Wordpress into my personal folder then moved it to /var/www/html/ it retained it's original context and was not allowed to be served by Apache. The test.html and the info.php files I created were created in /var/www/html/ and had the correct security context, so they were allowed to be served by Apache.

Anyway, I found the solution here - [[SOLVED] Apache 403:Forbidden on sub-directory](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6834)

I just needed to run the following command:

```
    sudo restorecon -r /var/www/html
```

Or, I could have disabled selinux with the instructions here - [Enabling and Disabling SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux.html)